# How to handle special characters in path variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am taking variable names from a path variable in my spring application.

However that fails in some cases when URL contains special characters

For e.g. http://www.loudletters.com/ll/rest/celebrityprofile/2S/Jan%20Min%C3%83%C2%A1%C3%85%C2%99 gives page not found error.

How to handle this?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing how you're constructing your URL from the Sting?

Answer (score 3):

I handle UTF-8 path variables just fine. What you need to do is:

- set UTF-8 for URIs in your servlet container configuration
- read the input as utf-8 (probably using spring's [`CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html))

The encoding and decoding should be done automatically by the servlet container and the browser.

Comment: @Bozho voting up for nice link.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the use of `java.net.URLDecoder` and `java.net.URLEncoder`?